# SpatialLinesDataFrameのmapviewによる表示

Tags: r

道路データ(http://nlftp.mlit.go.jp/ksj/gml/datalist/KsjTmplt-N10.html)を
mapviewパッケージを利用して表示させたいのですが，表示できません．
データによっては表示できるのですが，原因は何でしょうか？

```
data <- 道路データ
pj2000 <- CRS("+init=epsg:4612")
road <- maptools::readShapeLines(data, proj4string = pj2000)
mapview::mapview(road)
```

なお，下記の例題(SpatialLinesDataFrameクラス)は表示させることは可能です．

```
library(mapview)
mapview(atlStorms2005)
```

よろしくお願い致します．

データは簡単な例題やkokudosuuchiパッケージ(http://notchained.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/11/08/220222)
を利用できればよかったのですが，うまくできなかったため，
データ取得先のURLで示させていただきます．

Comment: 描画させる対象はどの都道府県でしょうか。ものによって仕様が異なるかもしれません。また、利用しているmapviewパッケージのバージョンについてもお教えいただけるとコメントの参考になります。

Comment: @cuttlefish44 さんの指摘にあるように、ファイル読み込み時のエンコード指定をしてみてはいかがでしょうか。`library(rgdal);

road <- readOGR("/Users/steverogers/Desktop/N10-15_13/", 
             layer = ogrListLayers("/Users/steverogers/Desktop/N10-15_13/")[1],
             encoding = "cp932");
mapview::mapview(road)`

Comment: コメントのコードで実行することができました．
ただ，フォルダ名に日本語を利用している場合，readOGRでエラーが発生しました．解決策はあるでしょうか？

Comment: 使用しているパッケージのバージョンです．
`mapview` 1.2.29
`rgdal`       1.2.5
`maptools` 0.8.41

Comment: フォルダ名の日本語でのエラーは不明ですが、readOGRを使わない方法で回避できないでしょうか `road <- sf::st_read("/Users/steverogers/Desktop/N10-15_13/",
                    options = c("ENCODING=cp932")); road.sp <- as(road, "Spatial"); mapview::mapview(road.sp)`

Comment: `readOGR(dsn = enc2utf8(dsn), layer = enc2utf8(layer))`とすることで読み込むことができました．
それぞれのpathをUTF-8にする必要があるようです(Windows)

Answer (score 0):

`data.frame`に含まれる日本語の一部がエラーの原因になっているようです。

```
data(atlStorms2005)
test1 <- test2 <- atlStorms2005

test1@data$test <- as.factor(c("日本語", "てすと"))
test2@data$test <- as.factor(c("日本語", "五十嵐"))

mapview(test1)   # 問題なく表示される
mapview(test2)   # 表示されない
```

Comment: githubからインストールしたmapviewパッケージを利用すると表示される場合がありました．ただ，Rstudioを再起動すると表示されないなど不安定です．
ほかに改善策はありますでしょうか．

Comment: @ogw; 日本語情報を`data.frame`に維持しつつでの良案は残念ながら思い浮かびませんでした、申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 0):

質問に回答してくださった方ありがとうございました．
データフレームの文字コードにより表示できないということがわかりました．
(windowsで確認)

```
data(atlStorms2005)
test1 <- test2 <- atlStorms2005

test1@data$test <- as.factor(c("日本語", "てすと"))
test2@data$test <- as.factor(c("日本語", "五十嵐"))

mapview(test1)   # 問題なく表示される
mapview(test2)   # 表示されない
```

データフレームを保存読込みすることで対応できます．

```
re.data.frame <- function(data, encoding = "UTF-8", fileEncoding="UTF-8"){
  write.csv(data, file("clipboard", encoding = encoding), row.names = F, fileEncoding=fileEncoding)
  fileEncoding=fileEncoding)
  tmp <- read_csv("clipboard")
  return(tmp)
}



test2@data <- re.data.frame(test2@data)
mapview(test2) # 表示できる
```